# cannot open fat jar from a desktop shortcut

Tags: nsis

the fat jar opens fine in the location i specified but it wont open when i call it through a desktop shortcut. Although if I right click on the icon and say open file location, it opens the correct file.

```
SetOutPath $INSTDIR
SetOverwrite on
File C:\jitconsole\JITConsole\jitconsole.jar
SetOutPath $INSTDIR\images
File C:\jitconsole\JITConsole\images\*
SetOutPath $INSTDIR\lib
File C:\jitconsole\JITConsole\lib\*
SetOutPath $DESKTOP
CreateShortcut $DESKTOP\JIT.lnk $INSTDIR\jitconsole.jar "" $INSTDIR\images\JIT_medium.ico
```

any help would be greatly appreciated
thanks

Comment: What's the shortcut's "Start In" directory?

Comment: the shortcut is on the desktop.CreateShortcut $DESKTOP\JIT.lnk $INSTDIR\jitconsole.jar "" $INSTDIR\images\JIT_medium.ico

Comment: @MarcB: $outdir, in this case that is $desktop (And yes, that is probably wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A .jar could open in any application, on my system it is set to open in WinRar!

You should create a shortcut that executes the correct command line:

```
CreateDirectory $Desktop ; Make sure desktop exists
SetOutPath $Instdir ; Sets the .lnk working directory
CreateShortcut "$DESKTOP\JIT.lnk" "c:\path\to\java.exe" "$INSTDIR\jitconsole.jar" "$INSTDIR\images\JIT_medium.ico"
```

This means you need to figure out the java path in the installer and if the java path changes your shortcut might break. It is probably a better idea to use a java loader app:

```
CreateDirectory $Desktop ; Make sure desktop exists
CreateShortcut "$DESKTOP\JIT.lnk" "$INSTDIR\MyJavaLoaderForMyApp.exe" "" "$INSTDIR\images\JIT_medium.ico"
```

Comment: thanks I got the shortcut working, i had some image issues. I made the path for the image absolute.But now i can't get the image on the shortcut I hope $INSTDIR\images\JIT_medium.ico is the correct way of doing it. I have the JIT_medium saved as a .png file.

Comment: @user1005747: .ico must be real icon files, try http://www.convertico.com/ for example...